# All dates in Stock ledger required

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below code which is giving data like in sheet one

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N3qg3F7fW1NB6Z3-ZIg-RAidGBlIwzma8DZbeMjLF20/edit?usp=sharing

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#temp')IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #temp
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#temp2')IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #temp2

Select [Entry No_],[Storage Type],[Location Code],[Primary Customer No_],[Posting Date],[Item No_],Quantity,[Quantity in Pallets]
,Case when Quantity > 0 then Quantity else 0 end as [In],
Case when Quantity<0 then Quantity else 0 end as Out

 into #temp from [XYZ$Item Ledger Entry] --where [Primary Customer No_]='AHMP000259'

Select [Storage Type],Sum([Quantity in Pallets])[Quantity in Pallets],[Primary Customer No_],[Item No_],[Posting Date],sum(Quantity)Quantity,
Sum([In])[In],Sum(Out)Out,
Sum(sum(Quantity)) over (Partition by ([Item No_]),([Primary Customer No_]) Order by [Posting Date],[Primary Customer No_])Closing

into #temp2
 from #temp  
 Group by [Primary Customer No_],[Item No_],[Posting Date] ,[Storage Type]
 order by [Primary Customer No_],[Item No_],[Posting Date]

 Select Cast([Posting Date]as date),*  from #temp2
 order by [Item No_],[Posting Date]`
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @GMB i want data for all 30 days, Kindly see attached , Missing date should come sheet.https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N3qg3F7fW1NB6Z3-ZIg-RAidGBlIwzma8DZbeMjLF20/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You would need to edit your question to provide more context, probably showing the expected output as well.

Comment: All your script does is move data from a physical table into a temporary table, then into a second temporary table. There's some manipulation going on, but nothing that I can see that would lose you an entire date from the final results.  From this I can only assume that the data in `[XYZ$Item Ledger Entry]` is not the same as the data in your Google Sheet?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - as it stands, you're asking us to do a lot of work, and your question seems very specific to your own circumstances, so other wouldn't benefit from seeing it answered.
At the very least, please include a schema, sample data, expected results and actual results. Please don't link to external resources
Ideally, boil the question down so we're not parsing a stored procedure that's doing a lot of work that's probably irrelevant to the question.